# connect to virtual machine on same laptop

Tags: virtual-machine

I have a laptop running Vista and just installed on it `Virtual PC 2007` that has a virtual machine (windows 7 OS). Is there a way to treat this virtual machine as a server on the same machine? I would like to be able to remote desktop to it from the host (same laptop the VM is on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to run the networking as "Bridged." For example, in Parallels, you'd do this:

[image]

That would allow the VM to have it's own IP. You should be able to access it via SSH using that IP address. This is untested, but it *should* work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should be able to do this either bridged or shared networking. Just have to figure out what the VM's IP address is and make sure to enable Remote Desktop.